# Spark Structured Streaming gives me error as org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'foreachBatch' does not support partitioning;

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks

I have design the below Structured Streaming code in Databricks to write to Azure Data Lake :

```
def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) {


  microBatchOutputDF.createOrReplaceTempView("updates")


  microBatchOutputDF.sparkSession.sql(s"""
   MERGE INTO silver as r
USING 
(
SELECT smtUidNr, dcl, inv, evt, smt, msgTs,msgInfSrcCd
FROM (
  SELECT smtUidNr, msgTs
  , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY smtUidNr ORDER BY msgTs DESC) as rank
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY smtUidNr ORDER BY msgTs DESC) as row_num
  FROM updates
  )
WHERE rank = 1 AND row_num = 1
)
as u
ON u.smtUidNr = r.smtUidNr 
WHEN MATCHED and u.msgTs > r.msgTs THEN
  UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT *
  """)
}

splitDF.writeStream.format("delta").foreachBatch(upsertToDelta _).outputMode("append").partitionBy("year","month","day").option("checkpointLocation", "abfss://checkpoint@mcfdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/kjd/test/").start("abfss://dump@mcfdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/main_data/")
```

When I try to execute this,it gives me error as follows :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'foreachBatch' does not support partitioning;
```

What is alternate way to use foreachBatch with partitioning?

Answer (score 4):

> What is alternate way to use foreachBatch with partitioning?

Use partitioning inside `foreachBatch`.

You could also write batches to a Delta table and run a separate query over the delta table to merge it with the other table.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please share the code for the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can establish the partitioning when you first create the delta table, then when you do subsequent upserts the partitioning will be maintained.
Here's an example:

```py
source_path = 'abfss://stage1np@youraccount.dfs.core.windows.net/example/student'
destination_path = 'abfss://stage2np@youraccount.dfs.core.windows.net/example/student'

# land some basic data in csv format
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'John','English','2021'), (2,'Jane','English','2021')], ['id', 'name', 'language', 'school_year'])
df1.write.format('csv').save(source_path, header='true')

# now process the initial data into a delta table, partitioned by 'school_year'
schema = StructType([StructField('id',StringType()),StructField('name',StringType()),StructField('language',StringType()),StructField('school_year',StringType())])
df = spark.readStream.load(source_path, format='csv', header='true', schema=schema)
query = df.writeStream.format('delta').outputMode('append').trigger(once=True).option('checkpointLocation', source_path + '/_checkpoints').partitionBy('school_year').start(destination_path)
query.awaitTermination()

spark.read.load(destination_path, format='delta').show()

# land additional inbound data with new and updated rows
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'Johnny','English','2021'), (3,'Jimmy','English','2022')], ['id', 'name', 'language', 'school_year'])
df2.write.format('csv').save(source_path, header='true', mode='append')

# now merge the new data in     
dt = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, destination_path)
def upsert(batch_df, batchId):
    dt.alias("current").merge(batch_df.alias("updates"), "current.id = updates.id").whenMatchedUpdateAll().whenNotMatchedInsertAll().execute()             
query = df.writeStream.format("delta").foreachBatch(upsert).outputMode("update").trigger(once=True).option("checkpointLocation", source_path + '/_checkpoints').start(destination_path)
query.awaitTermination()

spark.read.load(destination_path, format='delta').show()
```

If you want to put this into a function and have it check to see whether or not there's an existing delta table, you can use:

```py
DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, destination_path)
```